# How to color an inner column in bNiceMatrix

Tags: nicematrix

I would like to color the first column of the matrix (not the first row with the column indices). Any way to do this?

```
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, first-col]
           & 1      & \cdots & K \\
     1     & *      & \cdots & * \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    N      & *      & \cdots & * \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
```

It is easy for rows using rowcolor, but it is not clear to me how to do it for columns.

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE is based on the example from section 6.2 The tools of nicematrix in the \CodeBefore of [CTAN -- nicematrix](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) of page 17, changing `rowcolor` by `columncolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}
    \CodeBefore
    \columncolor{red!15}{1,3}
    \Body
           & 1      & \cdots & K      \\
    1      & *      & \cdots & *      \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    N      & *      & \cdots & *
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{vNiceMatrix}
    \CodeBefore
    \columncolor{red!15}{1-3}
    \columncolor{blue!15}{5}
    \Body
           & 1      & \cdots & K      & K+1 \\
    1      & *      & \cdots & *      & a   \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & b   \\
    N      & *      & \cdots & *      & c
  \end{vNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]