# Karnaugh map package: \implicantedge

Tags: diagrams, karnaugh

I am trying to highlight the eight vertical karnaugh map cells with one implicant as follows:
[image]

However, when I try to do it as stated in the documentation, it gives me this result:
[image]

Here is my Latex:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$b_4$][$b_3$][$b_2$][$b_1$]
        \minterms{0,2,4,6,8}
        \terms{10,12,13,14,15}{$x$}
        \autoterms[0]
        \implicantedge{0}{4}{12}{8}{2}{6}{14}{10}
 \end{karnaugh-map}
```

Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, always post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), snippets of code doesn't always provide the full information, for example, preamble. It might be interessting taking a look at how nicematrix highlights columns [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639092/140133).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates for this highlight are 0000 (0) and 1000 (8) on the left and 0010 (2) and 1010 (10) on the right. So:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\begin{document}
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$b_4$][$b_3$][$b_2$][$b_1$]
        \minterms{0,2,4,6,8}
        \terms{10,12,13,14,15}{$x$}
        \autoterms[0]
        \implicantedge{0}{8}{2}{10}
\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been trying to do this for a while.